# multiplayer java games using applets query?

Tags: java, applet, hosting, multiplayer

I'm newbie to java game programming  and till now was building games using jquery and html5 .
So I just want to know is it possible to build **multiplayer online game using java** which I can run in browser **without using any java hosting** .I have purchased one hosting plan but it's not providing hosting for java apps. I specifically need some info on how can I publish it online . Please provide link to any tutorial if it's there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a Java-based applet game that works without having Java-specific hosting.

From the perspective of the server, a Java applet is just another file that it serves up to the client web browser on demand.

You'll have to think about how you want to handle the server parts of a multi-player game though. Most multi-player games have a big server component to handle communications, updating game state etc. If you want to write these parts in Java, you will need to be able to run a Java Virtual Machine on the server.

Also be aware that multi-player game programming is hard, Java or otherwise. I'd suggest you get comfortable writing small single-player Java games before you embark on anything too ambitious.